# React のルーティング設定で真っ白な画面が表示されてしまう

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Reactの画面遷移のためにルーティングを学習中です。

下記のサイトを試しに自身で実施して実行すると、画面が真っ白になりました。

[ルーティングの設定 | React Router v6 はじめでもわかるルーティングの設定方法の基礎](https://reffect.co.jp/react/react-router-6#i-2)

最初はサイトのソースをそのままコピー＆ペーストで実行すると真っ白です。
そこで調査して、jsonファイルにhomepageを設定しましたが解決していません。
対処方法をご教授していただきたいと思います。
なお、App.cssは特に何も触っていません。

以下のコードで…

- ★の部分を入れて実行すると真っ白です。
- ★を除くと "Hello React Router v6" と表示されます。

App.js

```
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './routes/home';


// import About from './routes/about';
// import Contact from './routes/contact';


function App() {
return (
 <div className="App">              
    <h1>Hello React Router v6</h1>
     <Routes>                                                   ★
        <Route path="./" element={<Home />} />      　　　　　　 ★
     </Routes>                                                  ★ 
 </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js、package.jsonも記載します。
調査したら、package.json　にhomepageの設定が解決案としてありましたので
設定しています。

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
     <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-router-6",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "./",             ★こちらを設定しました。
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
```

Comment: `package.json` は途中で途切れているようにも見えますが、これで全部でしょうか？

Comment: ご質問、ありがとうございます。
＞package.json は途中で途切れているようにも見えますが、これで全部でしょうか？

全部ではありません。記載した下にもあります。標準で作成されている箇所は変更していません。★の箇所を追記しただけです。

Answer (score 0):

v6をインストールしていることを再確認してみてください。

npm install react-router-dom@6

Answer (score 0):

React の import の仕方は正しいでしょうか？
import する対象によって import 方法が異なります。

[React のimport {}のあるなしについて](https://terakoya.sejuku.net/question/detail/16886)

> 1. export defaultで公開してある（コンポーネントなど）→ 中括弧なしでimportできる
> 2. exportで公開してある（関数やフックなど）→ 中括弧をつけてimport